# Notification for edits made to posts

Tags: bug, editing, notifications

I no longer receive notifications (both on web and iOS app) for edits made to my posts by others. If I recall correctly, this didn't use to be the case previously. However, I can browse to the Responses section under my account overview page to see the notification listed.

I have first observed this behaviour a month ago. I would like to be notified for any edits made to my post(s).

Has something changed recently on the website? Or is this possibly a bug? Has someone else observed it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about minor edits like [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/359984/revisions), that's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). You're only notified of [substantial edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135961/295232); which edits are substantial is [not completely defined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/295232):

> There are a few rules in how "substantive" is defined, but typically one of the following should be enough to trigger a message:
>
> - edit to a question title
> - the edit in the post body should be over a threshold
> - the edit in code sections should be over another threshold
>
> The threshold varies from site to site. Retagging only is not considered "substantive" hence will not send notification.